# Read Blutooth Device data and print it

Tags: android, bluetooth, device, inputstream

Anybody can tell me how to display the bluetooth device (MyGlucoHealth meter) data in LogCat.  the following code :

InputStream  is = btSocket.getInputStream();

How to read data from "is" and print it. ?

Thanaks,
Chenna

Answer (score 0):

have a look http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth/source/browse/tags/AndroidBluetoothLibrary_0_1/AndroidBluetoothLibrarySamples/src/it/gerdavax/android/bluetooth/sample/BluetoothServiceSample.java

Comment: no friend. Thats a different issue..  i want to see the device data came via bluetooth on console ...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [BluetoothChat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) example. `ConnectedThread.run()` reads data from an `InputStream`.

```
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi dorzy,Thank you very much. But the code is unable to print the data on my Logcat. its telling : Software causes IOException. java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer.. Thanks, Chenna

Comment: You get the IOException when the connection gets lost. Are you sure you're connecting the devices?

Comment: yes iam sure the devices are connected and the errors coming after my gluco device  connection get lost..

Comment: If the connection is lost then you will get an IOException. If the devices are connected then any bytes sent by your device should be able to be retrieved from the stream by the android device. I am not familiar with the device you mention, so maybe I am misunderstanding your problem.

Comment: but there are no too many readings to send (probably 2 readings in the history..) the device keep on connecting for a long time (almost 2 or 3 minutes) ..  the device can send the data in that time easily...  as i guess..